# Advice on removing and replacing a door threshold

Tags: threshold

I'm looking for some advice on removing a door threshold between a hallway and bedroom.  The hallway has carpeting that's staying (for a few more years at least) while the bedroom is getting floating floors.  The problem that I've run into is that the door jamb sits on top of the threshold.  If I can remove the threshold without damaging it, I would reuse it because it matches all of the others in the hallway, but if there's no way to remove it without cutting it out then I would just get a new one.

So, my questions are:  Is there a good way to remove the threshold without damaging it?  If that means removing the jambs, is there a recommendation on how to do that without damaging the rest of the frame? Alternatively, could I leave the threshold and just have the floating floors butt up against them or do I need to ensure there's enough room for expansion?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually the door stops are just nail on the frame with small nails.  Running a small knife/razor blade carefully along the corners with the paint, you should be able to ply them off.  Work slowly from the bottom to top, loosening the nails a bit at a time.

Comment: @crip659 is right, and you only have to do one side!

Comment: ... or cut an inch off the bottom of the stops. Later nail them back, fill the crack and paint.

Comment: If you are re-doing the floor/carpet on both sides of the door, you could try to make them level and use an appropriate transition strip (or none at all!) instead of a heavy saddle like that one.

Comment: Is the threshold nailed into place?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible the threshold was installed after the door (jamb) was in place. So someone undercut the jamb either before or after it was installed to make space for the threshold.  The door jamb/door was installed, and the threshold slid under the jamb from either the hallway or the bedroom, then fastened down with some #18 brads, small finishing nails, or some construction adhesive.

If that's the case, you might able to cut through the nails/brads with a hacksaw blade that's slid under the threshold, after prying it up, gently.  Then bump the threshold out from under the jamb.

Comment: It would be a good use of those single end hacksaw handles I have seen.

Comment: Which I happen to have one, or two, or three of <wink>.  Also, a good excuse to go out and buy an oscillating tool!